# Dimensions of an algebraic expression

Tags: integration

From section 24 of the book "Integral calculus for beginners " by Joseph Edwards.

[image]

How to find the dimension of the algebraic expression, that the author is talking about? According to me the dimensions of 1/ $\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}$ should be $-1$ but the author states that is is $0$. Please explain because if x and a are linear then dx must be constant hence the degree of 1/ $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ should be $-1$ only

Comment: What do you mean by "dimensions" of $\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}$? Who is the author? Any link to understand what you are talking about?

Comment: Actually i dont know ...this was mentioned in article 24 of the book "Integral calculus for beginners " by joseph edwards

Comment: "but the author states that is is 0" No the author does not state that, and the dimension of $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ is $+1$, obviously.

Comment: "How to find the dimension of the algebraic expression, that the author is talking about?" In the example? As the author says, by assuming $a$ and $x$ and $dx$ are linear hence $a^2-x^2$ is quadratic, $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ is linear and $dx/\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ has dimension $0$.

Comment: @Did i have edited the question !!

Comment: "if x and a are linear then dx must be constant" Well, no, why do you think so?

Comment: @Did i though of it as a derivative of x ...thats why ...but now thats answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [author](https://archive.org/details/integralcalculus00edwarich/page/28) is saying that 
$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\,dx $$
has dimensions $0$ because $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ at the denominator is of dimensions $2\cdot (1/2)=1$ and $dx$ at the numerator is of dimensions $1$. So $1-1=0$.

By using the same argument,
$$\int\frac{1}{a^2+x^2}\,dx $$
is of dimensions $1-2=-1$.

Comment: Thank you , i never thought about dx

Comment: But if x is linear ,isn't dx supposed to be of 0 degree then?

Comment: $x=x^1$ is  of $1$ degree. $dx$ is a variation of $x$ (a difference of $x$) not a derivative.

Comment: hence dx is of 0 degree?

Comment: $dx$ is a variation of $x$ (a difference of $x$) not a derivative. So $dx$ has the same dimensions of $x$.