# What does 'dimensions' in this context even mean?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

The book on Integral Calculus by *Joseph Edwards* in its **24th Art.** says:

> Also it is a further help to observe the **dimensions** of each side. For instance, $x$ and $a$ being supposed linear, $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}}$ is of zero **dimensions**. There could therefore be no $\frac{1}{a}$ prefixed to the integral.

My question is what does the author mean by *dimensions*?

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3042310/dimensions-of-an-algebraic-expression) is a similar question but it doesn't really answer what the term *dimension* means in this context.

[Here](https://archive.org/details/integralcalculus00edwarich/page/28) is an archive if you want to read it yourself.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note that $dx$ has the same dimension as $x$, which has the same dimension as $\sqrt{x^2}$

Comment: Have you read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis)?

Comment: See [dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis).

Comment: If $a>0$ then the integral is $$\arcsin(x/a)$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dimensions here are related to what a physicist would think of as units.

Suppose that in this example $x$ represents a length, perhaps measured in centimeters. Then $dx$, which is a small change in $x$, is also measured in centimeters.

In the denominator, $x^2$ has units square centimeters. In order to subtract that from $a^2$ the units must match, so $a$ must be measured in centimeters too. Then $\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}$ in the denominator has units centimeters.

It follows that the quotient in the integrand is unitless (what the author calls dimensionless). Since the integral is just a sum, the definite integral is dimensionless too.

That's why the author can conclude that it must be wrong if you end up with the constant $1/a$ in front of the integral.

Comment: I see. I was aware of the dimensional analysis used in Physics but didn't think this was that... Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Presumably it is meant that the $dx$ portion has dimension $1$, which cancels out the one dimension in the denominator. This coincides with $\frac{dx} {a^2+x^2}$ having $-1$ dimensions. Abusing terminology, $dx$ is usually considered to be a "length," a "difference" in "adjacent" values of $x$. Some mean this more literally than others.